# Changing JAVA_HOME for weblogic gives problems with Security Realm

Tags: java, weblogic

I have downloaded `Java SE 1.6.0.45` from oracle and Installed on Oracle linux. Changes made to alternatives as well such that now `java -version` gives `1.6.0.45`.But when I changed `JAVA_HOME` in `setDomainEnv.sh` the Admin server startup failed with the below message:

```
java:Net.c:229:Java_com_bea_wcp_sctp_Net_initIDs:Assertion `ia_addressID' failed.
```

It seems that weblogic security realm is giving this message. I am a newbie to welogic especially to security realms.

Please help me figure out how to configure security realm to accept the new jdk installed.

Comment: When your server starts, the startWebLogic.sh script should echo out what JAVA_HOME is set to after `starting weblogic with Java version`. Does it look correct there? If it's somehow getting the wrong version of Java you might see that error. Worst case you could edit startWebLogic.sh instead and set JAVA_HOME

Comment: hi castling, thanks for replying. i made changes of JAVA_HOME and JAVA_VENDOR in setDomainEnv.sh and i echoed them in startWeblogic.sh and the version changes get reflected there.Googling out gave me a feeling that some Native file is giving this assertion problem.I checked the Linux arch of my machine again and uname -a gave me Linux ofss220310 2.6.39-100.5.1.el6uek.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Mar 6 20:26:00 EST 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
and the jdk i downloaded from oracle is jdk-6u45-linux-x64-rpm.bin.Both seems 64 bit hence compatible but still problem exists.Please Suggest.

Comment: On some pages there were suggestions that the JIT sometimes may cause problems.So i also tried disabling JIT via -Djava.compiler=none but still the issue exists.Adding -Djava.compiler=none to JAVA_OPTIONS I could see the same in arguments on server startup. This assures me that my changes are getting reflected.

Comment: Can you also verify your setDomainEnv file that the `if JAVA_VENDOR` section is correctly setting your JAVA_HOME